# T-SQL is it possible to use a variable in a select statement to specify the database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to do something like this without converting the sql to a string and calling exec

```
DECLARE @source_database varvhar(200)
SELECT @source_database = 'wibble'

SELECT * FROM SELECT @source_database.dbo.mytable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. I'm afraid not.

It is necessary to use dynamic sql in order to use a variable for either a database or column name.

Answer (score 2):

Only for stored procs without using linked server or dynamic SQL

```
DECLARE @myProc  varchar(200)
SELECT @myProc  = 'wibble.dbo.foobar'

EXEC @myProc
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another (not necessarily pretty) alternative:

```
IF (@source_database = 'wibble')
    USE wibble;
ELSE IF (@source_database = 'wibble2')
    USE wibble2;
ELSE
    RAISERROR(....)

SELECT * FROM dbo.myTable
```

If you have any real number of databases, this may be tiresome. But it's an option nonetheless.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I didn't put my question into the context of the solution that I am working on.  I have a source database and a target database so the use statement works fine to ensure the source database is correct but, I then need to explicitly reference the target database in the sql query.